# can't click on the element in selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on an element containing the phone number on this site, link down below. It's the element which says "Toon Nummer" 

[image: element location]


Finding the element is easy enough:

```
tel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@title, 'telefoon')]")
```

But if I want to click it, so far I know two ways:

```
tel.click()
```

This just returns ElementNotVisibleException. And the other way:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tel)
```

This just doesn't do anything, no error but no click either because the information doesn't get displayed. What else can I do to successfully click on this?

[link to site](https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-onderdelen/overige-onderdelen/a1019868022-opel-klapsleutel-2-knops-klap-sleutel.html?c=d97e27c274e75147b4afd0f5eb58c81b&previousPage=lr&casData=eUT25RJI4RoEnMHwxbHphQbdtFeqR0hg-y3w9c8b_6sNnIdRd4x9pSQ1SBNjg6ZVPkf9Bd9kNoW-AnlSgwlA3MyMxtJzFygXmXTb0_BhbljJCcSJ5DanwZiMzHJIjyZnj6H2JXhpFzgA50FKeS3aUfSwJjPoAQYnq4Ghk_9esv9eqeUsFD8BvxyhqtxHSuvnKmNrtnINNWWPHmOg8BJBBUQXDdxU6Rz6QhBAtJaaoJQWdCLdDPAmmHg_4B6PFb6MyiQzVlvFKRFp8VRJQl5f0XQrFEt70Q9g0meP7CZC-GfawK_pF6FLfUTO5K1IAH6rACnIl7qliHo4p4NUFTWQedL8w3zU22R3HByXc9mC-mCspjCHjQ3ZZw985DBFPdi5gcklCGIsWSjak8M1kYRIL8VwE0RWvUAirTK1nZfNDg4)

Comment: try this one `driver.find_element_by_css('.mp-Button.mp-Button--secondary')` and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
phone_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='vip-seller']/following-sibling::section/child::button")))  
phone_button .click()
```

Make sure you are importing these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

The Xpath you have written contains two web elements. Hope this will help.

Comment: thank you, this seems to work. I didn't realize there were 2 elements which correspond to my xpath search.

Comment: @DoctorEvil : No problem.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Toon nummer** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
# other lines of code
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//aside[@class='l-side-right']//button[@class='mp-Button mp-Button--secondary' and @title='Toon telefoonnummer']//span[contains(.,'Toon')]"))).click()
```

Comment: this gives NoSuchElementException

Comment: now it times out. If I try to search with your xpath, it doesn't find any elements. elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='mp-Button mp-Button--secondary']//span[normalize-space()='Toon']")

Comment: @DoctorEvil Yup, my bad, `<aside class="l-side-right">` is the node which makes your desired element unique. Updated my answer.