# How to click/find button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried to click the button **"Continuar >>"**  multiples ways by now, but it simply wont work. I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/marcas/Pesquisa_classe_basica.jsp')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type ='submit' and @title='Clique aqui para entrar na pesquisa']").click()
```

Edit adding the html of the element

```
<input type="submit" class="basic" value=" Continuar » " title="Clique aqui para entrar na Pesquisa">
```

Comment: What is the error ? Please share html of element you want click.

Comment: Perhaps the following site can help:
[can't click on the element in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810491/cant-click-on-the-element-in-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick solution, you can copy the xpath of the element by going to developer tools then right clicking on the element and then Copy> Copy XPath.
This may break depending on your situation though.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/marcas/Pesquisa_classe_basica.jsp')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="principal"]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as **`Continuar »`** you to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.basic[value=' Continuar » ']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='basic' and @value=' Continuar » ']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```